# margin-top results in [Window][Object]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this slice of html

```
<div class="info">

    <div class="vyrobky">
        <div class="vyrobky_holder">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

`.info` is centered in the middle of screen using trick

```
.info {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And i want to retrieve margin of `.info`, because all properties (top etc) are set to 0 i do it like this

```
var el = document.querySelector('.info');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

var top = style['margin-top'],
    left = style['margin-left'];

alert(
    "Top:" + top + '\n' +
    "Left:" + left
);
```

But top results in [Window][Object] the margin left property is fine what causes this unwanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

`top` is a property of the global object (`window` in a browser), see [`Window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top).

Nevertheless it can be used as a variable name inside a function to store a value. The following snippet appears to do what it should.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'load',
  function ()
  {
    var el = document.querySelector('.info');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

    var elTop = style['margin-top'],
        elLeft = style['margin-left'];

    alert(
        "Top:" + elTop + '\n' +
        "Left:" + elLeft
    );
  }
);
```

```css
.info{
  z-index: 0;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<div class="vyrobky">
<div class="vyrobky_holder">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still does the same thing

Comment: @Johnyb What browser are you using?

Comment: @Johnyb So am I. "-150px" is what I get for `top`. Not sure what could be different in your case.

Comment: i dont understand it , when i copy whole structure in jsfiddle it works too... but on my local it  does not work...

Comment: @Johnyb Maybe some other part of your JS code is interfering. I still don't know what's going on for sure, but you could try to use `addEventListener` to register the handler with the code or rename `top` to some different name. See the updated snippet above.

Comment: i tried it with just this piece of JS , didnt work either